# Pass a two dimensional array's index [0,0] as an argument for a method to set the letter of "O" or "X"

Tags: c#

I am creating a Tic-Tac-Toe application.  The game board will fill itself with the btnNewGame click event.

I would like to pass a two dimensional array's index (example [0,0] then [0,1] etc.) as an argument for the method setLetter() to set the letter of "O" or "X" for the labels text.

Any Help would be appreciated.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnNewGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create a Random Object
        Random rand = new Random();
        //Create a two-demensional array to fill the game board
        const int ROWS = 3;
        const int COLS = 3;
        int[,] gameboard = new int[ROWS, COLS];

        //Fill array with random numbers
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
            {
                gameboard[row, col] = rand.Next(2);
            }
        }


        //Fill each box with an O or X
        lblPosition1.Text = setLetter();
        lblPosition2.Text = setLetter();
        lblPosition3.Text = setLetter();
        lblPosition4.Text = setLetter();
        lblPosition5.Text = setLetter();
        lblPosition6.Text = setLetter();
        lblPosition7.Text = setLetter();
        lblPosition8.Text = setLetter();
        lblPosition9.Text = setLetter();

        string setLetter()//FIXME  
        {
            string letter = "None";
            if (gameboard[0, 0] == 0)
            {
                letter = "O";
            }
            if (gameboard[0, 0] == 1)
            {
                letter = "X";
            }
            return letter;
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: You put setLetter into the button click. When it is a brother of button click and all other functions (including the constructor). Lambdas would allow soemthing like that, but I doubt that advanced topic was what you are going for.

Comment: I'm only in level 1 classes currently and I imagine this will make more sense to me at a later time.  Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string setLetter(int row, int col)
{
    string letter = "None";
    if (gameboard[row, col] == 0)
    {
        letter = "O";
    }
    if (gameboard[row, col] == 1)
    {
        letter = "X";
    }
    return letter;
}
```

Pass in the coordinates in calls to `setLetter()` above.